# Integrate LSPlant framework with Android Studio project

Tags: android, runtime

I am researching on this framework (LSPlant Android Runtime Injection) and not sure how to start using it (https://github.com/LSPosed/LSPlant).

I followed the Quick Start to add the dependencies etc, then what is the next step? How do I call the APIs etc?

Sorry, I am not too familiar with code development etc so I am asking this question.